# 'webpack' not recognizing when running within the project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

When I try to run 'webpack' within the project the command line displays the following error:

> 'webpack' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have installed webpack with the command,

```
npm install webpack babel-core babel loader babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react react react-dom --save
```

Even though I tried this accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44221383/4536599) , it comes with another error.
[image]

webpack.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
entry: './src/index.js',
output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
    }]
}}
```

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "dummytextgen",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple dummy text generator",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "compile": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "webpack": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14"
  }
    }
```

Using OS - Windows 8 ,
npm version - 5.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the screenshot you need to update  the rules ,I have updated the configuration file its working fine. Please go through.

### webpack.config.js

```
var path=require('path')
    module.exports = {
        entry: './src/index.js',
        output: {
            path: __dirname + "/dist",
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }]
        }}
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "dummytextgen",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple dummy text generator",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "compile": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode development"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "webpack": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try to give the exact path to the webpack binary when you try to execute weback from within your project folder:

```
node_modules\.bin\webpack
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install webpack webpack-cli -g
```

should help